# Plex icon for Google Chrome in Launcher

Tags: google-chrome, launcher, icons, plex

- Ubuntu 16.04x64
- Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)
- Plex Version 3.2.1

Google Chrome works as expected until I open the Plex Launcher app.

Once I have opened the Plex Launcher (which opens the default browser to the localhost address for the Plex Media Server, the Plex Icon takes over for the Google Chrome icon.

- There are no longer indicators on the Chrome icon for open windows.
- Clicking on the Chrome icon opens new windows, rather than interacting with the already open windows.
- There are indicators on the Plex icon for open Chrome windows.
- Clicking on the Plex icon interacts with the already open windows.
- Closing out of Plex and then clicking on the Google Chrome icon restores the Plex icon.

So far the only way I have found to resolve the issue is to restart. If I open the Plex Media server the behavior returns.

You can see in the screenshots below that Chrome is open but the notification is next to the Plex icon. Also, the sub menu is specific to the Plex app, rather than Chrome.

Expected:

[image: Chrome Icon]
[image: Chrome Icon submenu]

Issue:

[image: Plex Icon]
[image: Plex Icon submenu]

I've asked this over at the [plex forums](https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/269150/plex-icon-for-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-launcher#latest) as well.